# Get latitude and longitude from zip code using PHP

Tags: php, google-api

I have a PHP page containing the following code to get latitude and longitude from a user input postal code.

But when I tried to echo the latitude and longitude, nothing is shown.

```
<?php
    function getLnt($zip){
    $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".urlencode($zip)."&sensor=false";
    $result_string = file_get_contents($url);
    $result = json_decode($result_string, true);
    return $result['results'][0]['geometry']['location'];
    }

    getLnt("750341");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
         $val = getLnt('90001');
         echo "Latitude: ".$val['lat']."<br>";
         echo "Longitude: ".$val['lng']."<br>";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you `var_dump($val)`?

Comment: The google result of your zipcode 750341 returns the below content `{
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}`. So if google returns nothing I think we can't manipulate it.

Comment: I've tested your code and I get `Latitude: 33.9697897
Longitude: -118.2468148` as output.

Comment: @PedroLobito May I know do you get the output? As I run my code, no output was shown.

Comment: It's not relevant to the outcome but I've commented `//getLnt("750341");` as it wasn't doing anything.

Comment: I have removed it from my code too. And it does not show anything too.

Comment: @benylim Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: This is the message i get 
Undefined offset: 0 on line "return $result['results'][0]['geometry']['location'];"

Comment: Do a `var_dump($result_string);` right after,  `$result_string = file_get_contents($url);` what does it show ?

Comment: It shows 
string(245) "{ "error_message" : "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. We recommend registering for a key at the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/", "results" : [], "status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" } "

Comment: You got your answer :)

Comment: I have included my api key in the url and i get another error message from it.
string(117) "{ "error_message" : "Requests to this API must be over SSL.", "results" : [], "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED" } "

Comment: I checked the code considering the fact that I am using active API(with well enough daily quota), the code gave me empty results too with postcode . It worked great when I used specific address instead of just postcode. Hope this helps if anyone is looking for it.

Answer (score 3):

Please add key parameter in api request. Key value you need to replace with google API key.

```
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".urlencode($postal_code)."&sensor=false&key=googleapi";
    $result_string = file_get_contents($url);
    $result = json_decode($result_string, true);
    if(!empty($result['results'])){
        $zipLat = $result['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
        $ziplng = $result['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I've tested your code and it works **perfectly**, my guess is that you've [exceeded your daily quota](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage) for the Google Places API Web Service.
A quick solution is to apply for a `key` at:

https://console.developers.google.com/

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is on API call must be on HTTP So change `http` to `https`

```
<?php
    function getLnt($zip){
    $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".urlencode($zip)."&sensor=false";
    $result_string = file_get_contents($url);
    $result = json_decode($result_string, true);
    return $result['results'][0]['geometry']['location'];
    }

    getLnt("750341");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure when but in 2019, we can use `components` in instead of `address` to get more accurary result.
eg: country is US and postal code is 41000

```
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=" . urlencode('country:US|postal_code:41000') . "&key=YOUR_API_KEY";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function getLnt($zip){
    $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".urlencode($zip)."&sensor=false&key=YOUR_KEY";
    $result_string = file_get_contents($url);
    $result = json_decode($result_string, true);
    return $result['results'][0]['geometry']['location'];
    }

  print_r(getLnt("462021"));
```